# Problem with getting loginName in viewmodel

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I have Views and ViewModels in separated projects.

What is the best practice to getting from some viewmodel config datas, for example username, set of privelleges for users, which I set after launch of application in App.xaml.cs

In older project I had views and viewmodels in the same project, and I was getting this datas by:

```
App _app = Application.Current as App;
var userName=_app.UserName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have your Views and VMs in seperate projects.  We normally use a singleton pattern to store application wide settings e.g.

```
public class ApplicationContext
{

    #region Declarations

    // Static instance of the application class.
    private static ApplicationContext _instance;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        //SecurityContext is a custom class that stores data on the current user  
        this.SecurityContext = new SecurityContext();
    }

    // Static instance creator.
    public static ApplicationContext Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new ApplicationContext();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public SecurityContext SecurityContext { get; set; }

    #endregion
 }
```

..and then to use it anywhere in the app:

```
var currentUserName = ApplicationContext.Instance().SecurityContext.CurrentUser.User.FullName
```